# How to return number of items in a list-of-lists?

Tags: python

Given a nested list type structure, I need number of items in the entire list.
For example:

```
a = [[2, [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]]]
# approach 1
def fun(items):
  vars = 0
  num = 0
  for item in items:
    print(item, item.__class__)
    if item.__class__ == list:
      num = fun(item)
    else:
      vars += 1
  return vars + num

# approach 2
str(a).count(",") + 1  # this works but not the approach I am looking for
```

So in the list `a` I expect to get 7 items in the overall list, but I see get only 2 from the method that I wrote in approach 1. What went wrong?

Comment: `num = fun(item)` should probably be `vars += fun(item)`

Comment: `if item.__class__ == list` is not the correct way to check if `item` is a list. Instead, use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `num`; you can add to `var` the result from the recursive call:

```py
def fun(items):
  vars = 0
  for item in items:
    if isinstance(item, list):
      vars += fun(item)
    else:
      vars += 1
  return vars

a = [[2, [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]]]
print(fun(a)) # 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reassigning the value of num each time. Change this line to:

```
num += fun(item)
```